How to expose Android Cuttlefish with a TURN server
I am running Android 15.0.0 r5 with Cuttlefish in an ARM host. I am orchestrating the application with Kubernetes and would like to expose the device outside the Kubernetes cluster.
So far I can test if the device works by using a bastion host with connectivity to the Pod IP (or the Cuttlefish device), however I won't be able to have this set-up in my prod environment, therefore I want to expose the device (and the webrtc streams, outside the Kubernetes cluster).
My client laptop and the Cuttlefish device will both be behind a NAT, therefore I assume that I will need a TURN server to act as a relay. However, I don't know how can I tell the Cuttlefish device to use the TURN server. Any help/guidance is appreciated.
